# How to make hidden div appear in another sortable list

Tags: jquery-ui

I'm dragging sortables from a grey ul list (parent group) to two yellow lists underneath. I am trying to have a hidden button in the grey sortable list appear when dragged into the yellow sortable lists.

I'm using a stupid method of display none and using a mouseUp event handler to make the hidden  button appear. It's not achieving the desired effect.

it is also important that the hidden button only appear in the bottom yellow boxes and not appear in the grey sortable lists.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

http://jsfiddle.net/equiroga/4At6J/4/

```
//Show js

  $(function(){
  $(document).mouseup(function(){ 
  $('.button, .button2, .button3, .button4, .button5').show(); 
  });
 });


//Sortable js
$(function () {
$("#sortable1").sortable({
    helper: "clone",
    connectWith: ".sortable",

    start: function (event, ui) {
        $(ui.item).show();
        clone = $(ui.item).clone();
        before = $(ui.item).prev();
        position = $(ui.item).index();
    },
    beforeStop: function (event, ui) {
        if ($(ui.item).closest('ul#sortable1').length > 0) $(this).sortable('cancel');
    },
    stop: function (event, ui) {
        if (position == 0) $("#sortable1").prepend(clone);
        else before.after(clone);
    }
});

$(".sortable").sortable({connectWith: ".sortable:not('#sortable1')"});
});
```

Comment: It would be useful to have a single button class for all buttons and then individual style classes, that way you can find the button no matter what style it is.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the top code and add this in the stop function:

```
ui.item.children('.button').show();
```

EDIT

I added a `bt` common class to all the buttons and then:

```
ui.item.children('.bt').show();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/stevemarvell/4At6J/6/

Comment: it worked! The code achieved the desired effect. And big props on fixing the css. I can't thank you enough! Cheers.